# sql query returning string instead of integer while using COUNT

Tags: php, sql

```
$query_products_records="SELECT @MyInt=COUNT(*) FROM products";
$result_query_products_records=mysql_query($query_products_records);
echo 'table records ...'.$result_query_products_records;
```

I used the above query to get the count of rows in table, but i got

`Resource id #4` on echo.

I have 3 records in the table.

Comment: Resource id is different thing from total count

Comment: You should fetch the result first. and dont use `mysql`, it is deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead

Comment: i don't want resource id, i just want the number of records in my table.

Comment: i used now
`$query_products_records="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products";
$result_query_products_records=mysql_query($query_products_records, $con);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result_query_products_records);
echo count($row);`
and it displaying 2, while i have 3 recods in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_query creates a resource.

That resource should be used with mysql_fetch_row().

```
mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($query));
```

For example. Or use it in while loop to extract more than one result.

PS: Also consider using mysqli extension over mysql. Its deprecated.

**The working code**

```
$result_data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM products"));
echo 'table records ...'. $result_data['c'];
```

Comment: after editing other's answers, i found your answer same like my final solution, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you are not fetching the resultset. you are using echo on `mysql_query()` hence the `Resource id #4` output. use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `mysql_fetch_array()` to get the result set and then echo it.

```
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_query_products_records);
// then echo as per required
```

Comment: print_r($res) will be used rather echo

Comment: either ways. `echo` a particular entry or `print_r` the entire array

Comment: used `mysq_fetch_array()` but not mysql_fetch_assoc().

Comment: `Array` is displayed on the browser, same as it was displaying while using `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Comment: @عثمانغني, it displaying `Array ( [COUNT(*)] => 3 ) `

Answer (score 0):

DO it like -

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');//connection
$qry = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry);//execute query
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);//fetch data
echo $res['total'];
```

Comment: i am using older version, i used `mysql` insted of `mysqli`.
my code is 
`$query_products_records="SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count FROM products";
$result_query_products_records=mysql_query($query_products_records, $con);
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_query_products_records);

echo $res['total_count'];`

& it displayed 3

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code instead

```
$query_products_records="SELECT anyFieldNeedInYourTable FROM products";
 $records=mysql_query($query_products_records);
 $result_query_products_records=mysql_num_rows(); 
echo 'table records ...'.$result_query_products_records;
```

and do not forget to replace  `anyFieldNeedInYourTable`  with true one.
and consider to move in mysqli

Comment: It will not work. You miss mysql_query now. Mysql_num_rows takes resource as parameter.